# displaying api data in laravel blade view [laravel 8] not showing data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm fetching data from the imdb api and when i try to display the data in a blade view I'm facing a lot of errors.

probably because I'm not sure what is the response I'm getting from the api.

please bare with me and thanks in advance for taking the time to read through my question.

so here are some of the available example responses from the api:

```
{
  "d": [
    {
      "i": {
        "height": 1500,
        "imageUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRiNDQwYzAtMzVlZS00NTI5LWJjYjUtMzkwNTUzMWMxZTllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDIzMzcwNjc@._V1_.jpg",
        "width": 1102
      },
      "id": "tt0944947",
      "l": "Game of Thrones",
      "q": "TV series",
      "rank": 36,
      "s": "Emilia Clarke, Peter Dinklage",
      "v": [
        {
          "i": {
            "height": 720,
            "imageUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTg4YzdjNTctNDg5Mi00ZmU1LTkzOWEtNmMyNDBjZjNhNTJiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXRyYW5zY29kZS13b3JrZmxvdw@@._V1_.jpg",
            "width": 1280
          },
          "id": "vi59490329",
          "l": "Official Series Trailer",
          "s": "3:19"
        },
        {
          "i": {
            "height": 1080,
            "imageUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTljMTZmNDUtNTEzNy00NDgyLTk2N2QtOTI3MGQyNWE0MTI5XkEyXkFqcGdeQWplZmZscA@@._V1_.jpg",
            "width": 1920
          },
          "id": "vi1097842713",
          "l": "The 8 Most Surprising Moments From \"Game of Thrones\" to Rewatch",
          "s": "3:39"
        },
        {
          "i": {
            "height": 720,
            "imageUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg0ODM4NTc3OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODAwODE1OTE@._V1_.jpg",
            "width": 1280
          },
  ],
  "q": "game of thr",
  "v": 1
}
```

I have tried to display the data in my blade view using a couple of ways the latest way I'm trying is this, blade.php:

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
    {{$item['d']}}
@endforeach
```

I'm getting this as a response:

> {"data":{"d":[{"i":{"height":4096,"imageUrl":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4NDA1OTA5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDQ2MDM5ODE@.*V1*.jpg","width":2764},"id":"tt2582782","l":"Hell or High Water","q":"feature","qid":"movie","rank":1332,"s":"Chris Pine, Ben Foster","y":2016},{"i":{"height":755,"imageUrl":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjM5ODQ5Nzc3OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTQzMzM4NjE@.*V1*.jpg","width":509}

the function in my Controller is this :

```
    public function api(Request $request)
    {
        $userInput = $request->input();

        $response = Http::withHeaders(
            [
                "x-rapidapi-host"=> "xxxxxxxxx",
                "x-rapidapi-key"=> "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            ]
        )->get("https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/auto-complete?q=",$userInput)->json();

        return json_encode(array('data'=>$response));


    }
```

I have also tired:

```
return view('view',['data'=>$response]);
```

but got different errors like:

> Illegal offset type.

and tried other ways as well but also didn't succeed.

what I'm I missing?? please help.

Comment: May be `$userInput` is being empty because `$request->input()` return empty array when you don't pass any parameters on it.

Comment: you are totally right sir but now when i got data not just an empty response i'm not able to show it on my blade view it's only showing like this: `{"data":{"d":[{"i":{"height":4096,"imageUrl":"https:\/\/m.media-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTg4NDA1OTA5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDQ2MDM5ODE@._V1_.jpg","width":2764},"id":"tt2582782","l":"Hell or High Water","q":"feature","qid":"movie","rank":1332,"s":"Chris Pine, Ben Foster","y":2016},{"i":{"height":755,"imageUrl":"https:\/\/m.media-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMjM5ODQ5Nzc3OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTQzMzM4NjE@._V1_.jpg","width":509}`

Comment: @JSTECH can you please demonstrate the right way to display data correctly in my blade view ? for example i wanna show the image and the rank

Comment: Your response data structure is incorrect, please resolve this issues. I am trying to figure out your issues. (please edit in question)

Comment: @JSTECH in the question I have provided the api example responses which in turn are provided by the imdb.api . i will add the response I've shown in the upper comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an update on my problem!

so i solved the issue i was having by using a for loop instead of a foreach loop!

that did the trick for me!

thank you all for taking the time to help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If this is the response from api ,,,,

> {"data":{"d":[{"i":{"height":4096,"imageUrl":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4NDA1OTA5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDQ2MDM5ODE@.V1.jpg","width":2764},"id":"tt2582782","l":"Hell
> or High Water","q":"feature","qid":"movie","rank":1332,"s":"Chris
> Pine, Ben
> Foster","y":2016},{"i":{"height":755,"imageUrl":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjM5ODQ5Nzc3OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTQzMzM4NjE@.V1.jpg","width":509}

then no need to json_encode buddy.

```
$data = $response
return view('view_path',compact('data'));
```

Comment: thank you dear sir I'm trying you suggestion but now i'm getting this error "compact(): Undefined variable: data "

Comment: $data = json_encode($response);

Comment: now i'm getting a new error sir wich is `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: $response die dump response variable and send output plz. Now issue is in api response why you are doing json_encode ???

Comment: I'm trying your solution dear sir now i'm getting this error: `Undefined index:d`

Comment: foreach ($data as $item)
    {{$item]}}
endforeach

Comment: can you pleas demonstrate the right way to access let's say the imageUrl ?

Comment: `foreach ($data as $item) {{$item}}` shows: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: foreach ($data as $item)
  foreach ($item as $2nditem)
    {{$2nditem]}} // this is your required object 
    endforeach
endforeach

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
public function api(Request $request)
{
$userInput = $request->input();

```
    $response = Http::withHeaders(
        [
            "x-rapidapi-host"=> "xxxxxxxxx",
            "x-rapidapi-key"=> "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        ]
    )->get("https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/auto-complete?q=",$userInput);

    return response->json(array('data'=>$response->body()));
}
```

Comment: thank you dear sir , I have tried what you have suggested but got this error: `Call to a member function body() on null ` .  what should i do next?

Comment: Can you please send me what is actually responded from the $response variable?

Comment: of course dear sir. this is the respond I'm getting `{"data":{"d":[{"i":{"height":4096,"imageUrl":"https:\/\/m.media-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTg4NDA1OTA5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDQ2MDM5ODE@._V1_.jpg","width":2764},"id":"tt2582782","l":"Hell or High Water","q":"feature","qid":"movie","rank":1332,"s":"Chris Pine, Ben Foster","y":2016},{"i":{"height":755,"imageUrl":"https:\/\/m.media-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMjM5ODQ5Nzc3OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTQzMzM4NjE@._V1_.jpg","width":509}`

Comment: Let me clear your send data direct controller to view? Am I right?

Comment: sorry for not understanding you clearly but i have tried `return view('view_path',['data'=>$response]);` and also tried `return view('view_path',compact('data');` to pass the data to the view but also got errors

Comment: If your api working perfect and have data then you will get body() method on response. Because Http::get() return you a Illuminate\Http\Client\Response instance which have `$response->body() ;
$response->json($key = null);
$response->object() : object;
$response->collect($key = null) 
$response->status();
$response->ok() ;
$response->successful() ;
$response->redirect();
$response->failed();
$response->serverError() ;
$response->clientError();
$response->header($header);
$response->headers();`

Comment: You can check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client)(Laravel documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a just demonstration code but you should do something like this.

This is not part of your solution (ignore it) but I wanted to show how I tested it. I have put your response data in my `test.json` file.

```
$response = file_get_contents(public_path('json/test.json'));

$object = json_decode($response);

$array = collect($object)->toArray(); // Not needed if you get an array type in $object
```

**Solution**

```
foreach ($array as $data) {
    $data = collect($data)->toArray(); // Not needed if you get an array type in $data
    foreach ($data as $items) {
        $items = collect($items)->toArray(); // Not needed if you get an array type in $items
        foreach ($items as $value) {
            $value = collect($value)->toArray(); // Not needed if you get an array type in $value

            $image = collect($value["i"])->toArray(); // Not needed if you get an array type in $value["i"]

            $imageUrl = $image["imageUrl"];
            $rank = $value["rank"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear sir for your efforts and patience, but I'm still getting errors. just not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Did you get data in `$data` or not?

Comment: i did using your provided example code.